# How to check if string compliant exact pattern using regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

How to check if any text compliant to following rule.

**Rule [any letter] [-] [any number] [:] [any letter or number]**

eg:`ABC-123:Sample message`

**Perl Code Snippet**

```
print verifyMsg("ABC-123:Sample message");

sub verifyMsg{

    my ($content) = @_;
    if ($content =~/^[a-zA-Z][-][0-9 :a-zA-Z]$/){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

It always returns 0.Please let me know how to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Rule [any letter] [-] [any number] [:] [any letter or number]

However, the input string provided in the question also contains a whitespace. So, according to that formula and the input string, you need

```
/\A[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+:[A-Za-z0-9\h]+\z/
```

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more (due to the `+` quantifier) ASCII letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `[A-Za-z0-9\h]+`  - 1 or more alphanumeric chars and *horizontal* whitespaces (NOTE: if you allow any kind of whitespace teplace `\h` with `\s`. If you only allow regular soaces, keep the space as in the original pattern.)
- `\z` - the very end of string.

See the [Perl demo online with this regex](https://ideone.com/oWSbyR).

Comment: The last character class in the example also includes a space.

Comment: @Sobrique: Yes, but the requirements do not mention that. It is written *any letter or number*.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: No longer, I replaced `$` with the `\z` anchor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the above regex didnt work when i put into my code but your previous pattern worked. `~/^[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+:[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/`

Comment: @gihan: Ok, I have reverted the whitespace pattern.

Comment: @gihan: My answer got downvoted for some reason. Maybe because of the `\s` that worked for you. Does replacing `\s` with `\h` (horizontal whitespace) work for you? Like `\A[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+:[A-Za-z0-9\h]+\z`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew replacing with `\s` with `\h` works fine. here is the regex `[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+:[A-Za-z0-9\h]`

Answer (score 2):

You need a `+` after your `[a-zA-Z]` because there's 3 characters, not 1. And the same for your other character class. Otherwise they match just one letter/just one number.

```
if ($content =~/^[a-zA-Z]+[-][0-9 :a-zA-Z]+$/){
```

Will return '1'.

But that's still not quite right, because you're matching '1 or more letters from practically anything, which isn't what you're after. So I'd probably:

```
/^[A-Z]+-\d+:/i
```

Which matches 'word'-'digit' a start of line followed by colon, and lets the 'message' be anything.

Or you could capture it:

```
print verifyMsg("ABC-123:Sample message");

sub verifyMsg {

   my ($content) = @_;
   if ( my ( $msg_code, $message ) = $content =~ m/^([A-Z]+-\d+):(.*)/i ) {
      print "$msg_code $message\n";
      return 1;
   }
   else {
      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Your check will succeed if the string also has a newline at the end in addition to the specified characters. It may or may not be acceptable to let that slip.

Comment: Word is more than letters, so `\w` will match digits and underscore. OP probably wants to keep `[a-zA-Z]+` there.

Answer (score 1):

In scalar context `m//` returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails. By adding `0`, we coerce those to be 1 and 0, respectively.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

while (my $case = <DATA>) {
    last unless $case =~ /\S/;
    my ($msg, $expected) = split '\s+=>\s+', $case, 2;
    ok(verify_message($msg) == $expected, $msg);
}

done_testing;

sub verify_message {
    0 + (
        $_[0] =~ m{
            ^                  # beginning of the string
            [A-Za-z]+        - # alphabetic part of identifier
            [0-9]+           : # numeric part of identifier
            [A-Za-z0-9]+       # alphanumeric sequence
            ([ ][A-Za-z0-9]+)* # possibly more alphanumeric sequences, space separated
            \z
        }x
    );
}

__DATA__
ABC-123:Sample message => 1
123-ABC:Sample message => 0
ABC-123:1 2 3 4 5 6 7  => 1
abc-123:Call 5551212   => 1
```

Output:

```
ok 1 - ABC-123:Sample message
ok 2 - 123-ABC:Sample message
ok 3 - ABC-123:1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ok 4 - abc-123:Call 5551212
1..4
```

#### Notes:

`$` will match an optional newline at the end of the string. By using `\z` to refer explicitly to the end of the string, I avoid accidentally letting a newline slip. Sometimes it is OK to let them through, sometimes they may lead to unexpected consequences later, so I recommend disallowing them unless they are explicitly allowed.

You can add more and play with the test cases to see if the specification is complete: For example, test 4 would have failed if there had been dash in the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
print verifyMsg("ABC-123:Sample message");

sub verifyMsg{

    my ($content )= @_;
    print"$content\n";
    if ($content =~/^[a-z]+-\d+\:[\w\s+]+$/i){
       return 1;
    }
    else{
      return 0;
   }

 }
```